# How do I use a return value straight from a function as a bitstring instead of a formatted number?

Tags: c, floating-point, int, type-conversion, bitstring

How do I get the effect of `intVariable = *(int*) &floatVariable` straight from a function instead of having to save the output of the function to a dummy variable first?

i.e.

```
float functionWithFloatTypedReturn(int input) {
    [enter code here]
    return serialStringStruct.floatRetVal;
}
...
intVariable = [desired code] functionWithFloatTypedReturn(commandCode);
```

Background: I have a function that reads from a serial response given by someone else's hardware. There is legacy code and curiosity about language capability motivating continued use of a singular function. If the function returns the numerical value '1', it could be either 0x3f800000 or 0x1, depending on the input to the function (which determines which command is given to the hardware). The serial string coming from the hardware gets broken up independent of type into a struct by a call of memcpy.

Comment: If the called function could return either 0x3f80000 or 0x1, why not just test the result to see whether it is either 0x3f800000 or 0x1? Also, if the called function is returning either a floating-point 1 or an integer 1, are you sure how the value is being returned in the underlying application binary interface (ABI)? (How is it being returned in the hardware?) You would need to declare the function in C to match its behavior and, if it sometimes returns `float` and sometimes returns `int`, and the ABI handles those differently, you have a bigger problem than reinterpreting the `float` bits.

Comment: Luckily for me, since this is for embedded, I have a lot more explicit control over which type to expect in the code calling this function. There are a number of usage examples in other parts of the code that show the u32 ints get treated the same as floats. As I mentioned, I was also curious about this corner case of using the language. In case you were curious, I get the value in a block of bits sent in consecutive serial reads on a UART. The values are stored in an unsigned char array to keep the order and then the array's memory is copied into a struct designed to match the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
intVariable = (union { float f; int i; }) { functionWithFloatTypedReturn(commandCode) } .i;
```

This uses a compound literal containing a union to reinterpret the bytes of the value (which is supported in C 1999 and later).

Note that it is usually advisable to use an unsigned integer rather than an `int` to access the bits of floating-point encodings, because unsigned integers are less prone to certain issues such as sign issues with bit shifts.

You must also ensure that the two types you are use have the same number of bytes in your C implementation.

This code accomplishes the reinterpretation without an intermediate C variable. However, that does not mean it will be any more efficient in the machine language implementation.

Comment: Nice trick.  Note that the `float` comes first here (as it should, the initializer for a union initializes the first member).  (I'd still prefer an inline function, which would be more readable and with any half-decent compiler should produce the same machine code.)

Comment: I'd give this a favorite answer were it possible.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can't, in part because many compilers return floating point values in a floating point register (or on the FPU stack) and therefore they have to be stored to "regular" memory before you can access them in bitwise fashion.</strike>

You can use an inline function to do the conversion.  Note that Standard C does not define the effect of treating a floating point bit pattern as an integer bit pattern (or vice versa), but it's OK to depend on your implementation here since, well, you *have* to.  Just put this in some sort of "depends on implementation" file (header, module, whatever).

(I'd suggest looking at a way to refactor this a bit to hide the hardware variability from the rest of the code.)

Comment: (a) You can, as other answers have shown. (b) Whether separate floating-point registers are used to return floating-point values is unrelated to whether the C language provides the power to express the desired assignment.

Comment: Yeah, there's basically no way to do this that's not more confusing than concise. Just do it in a utility funtion the verbose way.

Comment: It is true that the ultimate machine code coming out of the compiler is not dictated by particular source-language constructs, nor vice versa.  But I have found that people "feel better" about assigning to a temporary when they see that the assignment is actually required on their particular machine anyway.  In other words, the now struck-out "in part" section was meant to say "don't worry about the apparent store to memory".

Answer (score 0):

If you have a compiler that supports the C99 standard, you can use a compound literal:

```
intVariable = *(int *)&(float){ functionWithFloatTypedReturn(commandCode) };
```

As Eric Postpischil notes in comments, a `union` does not have the same aliasing issues that pointer type punning does:

```
intVariable = (union { float f; int i; }){ .f = functionWithFloatTypedReturn(commandCode) }.i;
```

This suggests a better approach, however - change the `floatRetVal` member of the struct to a `union` containing a `float` and an `int`, and directly return that `union` type from the function:

```
union retval {
    float f;
    int i;
};

union retval functionWithUnionTypedReturn(int input) {
    [enter code here]
    return serialStringStruct.floatOrIntRetVal;
}
```

Then code that knows it will get a `float` return type uses:

```
floatVariable = functionWithUnionTypedReturn(commandCode).f;
```

and code that knows it will get an `int` return type uses:

```
intVariable = functionWithUnionTypedReturn(commandCode).i;
```

Comment: If you are going to use a compound literal, you ought to use a union rather than casting pointer types. The C 1999 standard and later supports the former and not the latter.